# Volume change of solute addition to solvent

Tags: thermodynamics, aqueous-solution, concentration

When making and manipulating high concentration stock solutions of sugar excipients, is there a way to predict the corresponding volume effect that occurs? I am asking in order to be able to create end solutions with exact wt/volume concentrations.

I know about partial molar volumes and some of the thermodynamics of mixing, but am wondering if there are models and/or correlations to predict the volume behavior of some of these solutions.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry! Take the [tour](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here) using $\LaTeX$ syntax. If you receive useful answers, consider [accepting](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) one.

Comment: You'll probably have to research published correlations and/or predictive models for your solvent-solute system. I am not aware of any "generally accepted" models, maybe others more specialized in this area will be able to comment. This topic comes up a lot in my estimation, I would recommend searching through this Exchange for related questions.